# How to get name of JAR which is a desktop application run from?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I have created simple library [AppInfo](http://appinfo.sourceforge.net/) providing an easy way to show always valid, automatic updated information about a version of running software in Java applications, which is especially useful in conjunction with automatic builds from CI server.

In my library it is necessary to read MANIFEST.MF from JAR (in case of a desktop application) which is the end application run from (not from any other on a classpath). Currently I use a solution based on an idea taken form Sun's forum (which link to is not working anymore):

```
String classContainer = classFromRightJar.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
URL manifestUrl = new URL("jar:" + classContainer + "!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

and it generally works, but it forces developer of a desktop application to create additional bean configured with a name of a class which is located in specific JAR.

Is there a better/generic solution which gives a name/location/MANIFEST.MF of/from JAR which is a desktop application run from?

Thanks for your help
Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "forces developer of a desktop application to create additional bean..." do you mean that you don't want them to ever have to reference any of their application's class names at all? If so, then there probably isn't any 100% reliably way of doing it, but one approach could be to call java.awt.Frame.getFrames() and check for non-java* subclasses of JFrame. E.g.:

```
for (Frame frame in Frame.getFrames()) {
    if (frame.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("java"))
        continue;
    URL manifestURL = frame.getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    // do something with the manifest
}
```

This will break down if the application doesn't subclass the JFrame/Frame themselves, so you might also want to walk through the children of the frame to check for subclasses of the children as well.

Another approach might be to grab Thread.getAllStackTraces() and walk through all of them (especially the "main" thread) looking for the main class that started the application, and then grab the manifest for that class.

As I say, though, there probably isn't any 100% reliable way to do it, since the application may not use any custom subclasses and the stacks for the threads might have a mixture of different applications.

Comment: The idea was to create a library which is attached and works. I was afraid if there is a way to do it in a reliable way. I will probably force end application developer to create a String bean with a name (+package) of class from the main archive. It is still easy to do and much more safe. Thanks for your answer.
Btw, nice hack with stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

There's a system property "sun.java.command" that contains either the jar name or the class name plus all the main() method arguments. So for invocation

```
java -jar test.jar arg1 arg2
```

you'd get "test.jar arg1 arg2" and for

```
java test.Test arg1 arg2
```

the property value would be "test.Test arg1 arg2".
As the property's name would suggest, it's not "official" (does not have to work on non-Sun/Oracle implementations). I checked it on Java 7, don't know when it was introduced.